Does the normalization of monomial curves inject into the original monomial curve?
I've seen this fact that if $R=K[t^2,t^3]$, then the induced map $\pi:\text{Spec}(\tilde{R})\rightarrow \text{Spec}(R)$ is injective, where $\tilde{R}=K[t]$ is the normalization of $R$. My question is whether this generalizes to all monomial space curves. That is, if $R=K[t^{a_1},\cdots,t^{a_n}]$, is $\pi:\text{Spec}(\tilde{R})\rightarrow \text{Spec}(R)$ an injection?
(Right now I'm just assuming $K$ is a field of characteristic zero but we can strengthen or weaken this condition as needed.)
Thanks!

Related https://mathoverflow.net/q/40960/2841

Do you know how $\tilde{R}$ looks like?

@MartinBrandenburg I'm pretty sure $\tilde{R}$ is always $K[t]$ but don't have a rigorous proof. At the very least it should be true if $\gcd(a_1,\cdots,a_n)=1$. Also ty for the link I will check it out. (i read the post and appreciate it, though the counterexample of a node is not included in the class of monomial curves)

Well for $k[t^2]$ that's already normal. But we can always reduce to the case that the gcd $d$ is $1$ right? Think of the variable $t^d$.

@MartinBrandenburg that's fair, I think I wanted to avoid any technicalities around possible nilpotency/multiplicity. My scheme theory/geometry is quite weak so I was playing it safe.
